# What to name a new interface that is replacing an existing one?

Tags: naming, refactoring, interfaces

We're redesigning our application's plugin interface, so we're using the Adapter pattern with our proof-of-concept design to show that the new interface will function without committing to using it in the application itself.

We don't know what to call this new interface. It serves the same purpose as the old one - let's call that one `CAbstractAppPlugin`. Furthermore it will likely be, like its predecessor, an abstract class rather than a pure virtual interface (C++) indicating that we should still use "CAbstract" instead of "I". Slapping a "New" or "2" onto the name seems silly, but adopting a very similar name could lead to confusion until the old one is deprecated.

So how do you name a thing X that's replacing thing Y?

Comment: What's better about the new one? Could this be part of the name?

Comment: If it's temporary, you should live with silly.

Comment: @TravisChristian: For added compatibility, consider having your V2 abstract class inherit from the original abstract class.  That may allow old code to work without modification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless they're something conceptual that you can add to the name, I'd just go with `CAbstractAppPlugin2` or something similar.  Your documentation can identify the differences.

`CAbstractAppPluginWithSuperSizeFunctionAdded` seems equally ridiculous, if not more so.

Comment: A very similar option would be to go with `CAbstractAppPluginV2`.

Comment: @Bobson: I thought about that, but felt that V2 might imply that it is a part of a larger version encompassing the entire application, not just that particular interface.

Comment: We're going with `V2` which it turns out has been used on some regularly updated schemas in our code base.